# Is there any method to embed $K_p$ into a orientable surface?

Tags: graph-theory, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

It is known that $K_p$ can be embedded into genus $g=\lceil{\frac{(p-3)(p-4)}{12}}\rceil$ orientable surface. Do we know how to embed $K_p$ into the genus $g$ orientable surface?

Comment: Did you learn anything from the proof that it *can* be embedded which is pertinent to your question?

Comment: @Lee Mosher, I read the proof (may be sketch of the proof) from 'Graph Theory, Frank Harary'. There is used 'g \geq the number' and 'g \leq the number' so they are equal. So the answer of your question is no.

Comment: Well, if you have read the proof, or a sketch, then the better way to write your question is to tell us what part you understand, where you got stuck, etc. etc.